# Why does Visual Studio say I have stack overflow if I don't have any data structure codes written in my program? C++

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2013, stack-overflow

I wrote my program based on checking if regular expression is valid or not. I simply put my inputs like `a` or `ab` so when my programs runs and I type an input, I get this nasty error via a window pops up,

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00CC6FD9 in RE.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow     
(parameters: 0x00000001, 0x009E2F94).
```

In the xstring file, according to my VS

```
    value_type *_Myptr()
    {   // determine current pointer to buffer for mutable string
    return (this->_BUF_SIZE <= this->_Myres
        ? _STD addressof(*this->_Bx._Ptr)
        : this->_Bx._Buf);
    }
```

I mean, I don't have a data structure reference written. What's up with this? I think my program is very simple straightforward. My program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string input;
int index;

void RE();
void F();
int nextChar();
void consume();
void match();

int nextChar()
{
    return input[index];
}

void consume()
{
    index++;
}

void match(int c)
{
    if (c == nextChar())
        consume();
    else
        throw new exception("no");
}

void F()
{
    if (nextChar() == 'a')
        match('a');
    else if (nextChar() == 'b')
        match('b');
    else if (nextChar() == 'c')
        match('c');
    else if (nextChar() == 'd')
        match('d');
    else if (nextChar() == 'a')
    {
        match('(');
        RE();
        match(')');
    }
}

void RE()
{
    if (nextChar() == 'a')
    {
        RE();
        RE();
    }
    else if (nextChar() == 'a')
    {
        RE();
        match('|');
        RE();
    }
    else if (nextChar() == 'a')
    {
        RE();
        match('*');
    }
    else if (nextChar() == 'a')
        F();
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a regular expression: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    input = input + "$";
    index = 0;

    try
    {
        RE();
        match('$');

        cout << endl;
        cout << "** Yes, this input is a valid regular expression. **";
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "** Sorry, this input isn't a valid regular expession. **";
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you knew what recursion is, you wouldn't claim there wasn't any in your code...

Comment: RE() is a recursive function that gets in an infinite loop and fills the stack. This is why you get a stack overflow.

Comment: "Mutual Recursion" I believe it's called.

Comment: BTW, your use of exceptions is broken. Don't use `new exception` (avoid `new` in general!) and don't `catch(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `RE` is testing if the next char is `a`. If yes it calls RE() twice. The first RE() checks again if the next char is `a`, and this repeats in an "infinite" loop until you get a stack overflow.

As soon as you RE() function will meet an `a` as next char you will get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Since the function

```
 void RE()
 {
        if (nextChar() == 'a')
        {
            RE();
            RE();
        }
...
}
```

Notice RE calls nextChar() == 'a' **WITHOUT** a call to consume(), thus when the next RE() is called inside the if statement, which will have nextChar()=='a' again since there was no cosume. Which again will call RE() , which will have nextChar()=='a' again since there was no cosume.Which again will call RE() , which will have nextChar()=='a' again since there was no cosume..... Repeat this a couple of thousand times and eventually the computer no longer has space on the stack for all the function information since it needs to push return information to the stack, thus it tells you 'StackOverflow exception'.

To fix this simply add a consume() call inside RE() !

Comment: Okay this sounds reasonable, but where do I put consume() inside RE(), exactly?